# Why does GEE produce different random column value at each run?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Every time I run this code on different machines, GEE throws a different series of random values. I thought the seed parameters is designed for creating same/reproducible values. Here I provide some example code for this:  (https://code.earthengine.google.com/914f933b7103f3bfe079f33e4f42f113).

```
var bands=  ['B2'];

var Sentin = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(geometry2)
    .filterDate('2017-05-01', '2017-06-30')
    .median();

var D = Sentin.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 10,
  tileScale: 10,
  geometries :true
});

var D2 = ee.List.sequence(1, 10).map(function(seed){ 
      var cls11= D.randomColumn("random", seed)
      return cls11;
});

print(ee.FeatureCollection(D2).toList(10).get(9));
```